# Find free nodes on cluster with SGE

Tags: pbs, sungridengine

I'm looking for the SGE equivalent to PBS's "qstat -freenodes", basically I want to find all nodes that have nothing running. Suggestions?

Comment: can you explain what things have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an exclusive resource associated with the hosts you can 
use qhost:

```
qhost -l exclusive=TRUE
```

This should work even if you make the exclusive resource non-requestable.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
pbsnodes -l free
```